# How to find the next `n` files and `n+1`-th file for each file listed by `ls -1`

Tags: bash

In a directory, for each file listed by `ls -1 .` in the default order which is the lexicographic order, I want to do the following

1. find the next `n` files starting from and including the file, putting them into an array named `train`, and copy them into a subdirectory `tmp`.
2. find the `n+1`-th file, putting it into a variable named `test`
3. perform some operation on `train`, `test`, and `tmp`. Remove files in `tmp`.

`train` and `test` are reused, and supposed to be overwritten for each file listed by `ls`.

`tmp` is supposed to be empty right before starting the above steps for each file listed by `ls`.

The three steps are performed on each file except the last `n` files listed by `ls`, because there is no `n+1`-th file starting from each of them.

I wonder how to implement the above in bash? Thanks.

**For example**,

suppose `n` is 2, and the files listed by `ls` in the current directory are:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
```

for `a`, I will find `a` and `b` and put them into array `train` and copy them into dir `tmp`, and find `c` and put it in   variable `test`. Then perform some operation on `train`, `test` and `tmp`. Finally, empty dir `tmp`.

for `b`, I will find `b` and `c`, and put them into array `train` by overwriting it,  and copy them into dir `tmp`, and find `d` and put it in   variable `test` by overwriting it. Then perform some operation on `train`, `test` and `tmp`. Finally, empty dir `tmp`.

Then the above is performed on `c` and `d`, but not on `e` and `f`, because `n`=2.

Comment: If your files name don't contain newline, then `ls | tail -n +3 | head -n2` gave you the 3rd and 4th files.

Comment: Don't parse `ls`, that's a dirty habit

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a all
all=(`ls -1 | grep -v '^tmp$'`)
n=2
i=0

while [ $((n+i)) -lt ${#all[*]} ]; do
    declare -a train
    j=0
    while [ $j -lt $n ]; do
            train[$j]=${all[$((i+j))]}
            cp ${all[$((i+j))]} tmp/
            j=$((j+1))
    done
    test=${all[$((i+j))]}
    i=$((i+1))
    # do something:
    echo "loop $i: contents of tmp/ are" $(ls tmp)", test=$test"
    rm -f tmp/*
done
```

First put all the files in the array `all`.

Now loop while there's space in the array (offset `i` plus number `n` is less than the length of the list of files).

Use a loop to put `n` filenames into array `train` starting from offset `i`, and copy the file into subdirectory `tmp`. After the loop the next filename is put into `test`.

Now "do something".

Increment the offset `i` and loop again.

I personally would use perl for this.